# edit python file with ide software directly from c folder

Tags: python, windows, ide

I'm currently doing an internship. I have a Windows program (visual components) that I need to use to control robots in an virtual environment.

You can add to some elements in the program a Python script to do more advanced things. These Python scripts are stored in a few specific folders on the C drive.

If you are in the editor of the program it's just like notepad. I'm new to programming so I would like to use an IDE so that I can import a module and see which functions I can use so that when I type "system." and the IDE give me what is possible after the dot.

Problem is when I use PyCharm to open the file directly the modules aren't recognized, however they need in to be in one of those underlaying folders because in the direct editor in the software recognized the module without problems.

How can I configure PyCharm to recognize the modules?

Comment: I changed the question so that it won't be closed for asking for a software recommendation. The question needs some clarity about how you are opening files with PyCharm. If you are using a project, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for PyCharm: File -> Settings -> Project -> Project structure.

From there, you can 'Add Content Root' and point to the other folders that contain the data you want to be able to edit.

These should then appear on the Project Tab.

HOWEVER, you should be aware that doing this appends these folders to your PATH (where python looks for modules).  Depending on your project structure, you may end up importing some files you weren't expecting to.